# Deployment error - Unknown user permission

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, migration-tool

I could not deploy profile that contain ManageConnectedApps permission, via ant migration tool

Below is the XML version

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <name>ManageConnectedApps</name>
</userPermissions>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when you use a lower version API than when the feature is introduced. Please make sure you have updated your Ant software recently, and your package.xml file is at least version 39.0.

Comment: We are using version 41.0 in package.xml and also in ANT.